# How to read specific value from button in js function

Tags: javascript

I have several buttons contain some values:

```
<button class="Hotspot" onclick="ChangeView()" slot="hotspot-1" camera.Orbit='2.895deg 85deg 27.92m' ;>
```

and I need to create function that read *camera.Orbit* value from button's container after click on it:

```
function ChangeView() {
    const modelViewer = document.querySelector('#orbit-demo');
    modelViewer.cameraOrbit = camera.Orbit ???
}
```

I have no idea how to solve this. I do not use getElementbyId because it has to work for all buttons (not specific one).
I barely can JS.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute):

```js
function ChangeView() {
  const modelViewer = document.querySelector('#orbit-demo');
  let orbit = modelViewer.getAttribute('camera.Orbit')
  console.log(orbit)
}
```

```html
<button class="Hotspot" onclick="ChangeView()" slot="hotspot-1" camera.Orbit='2.895deg 85deg 27.92m' id="orbit-demo">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onclick function passes the click event to the method. You can take the target of this event (the button element) and acquire tha attribute like that.

```
onclick(e => changeView(e))
ChangeView(e) {
    // do things with e.target.???
}
```